# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на класс left__item, менялся цвет картинки и добавился элемент с классом "line"

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```
<li class="left__item">
  <span class="image"></span>
  Heading title one
</li>
```

CSS

```
.left__item {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #9fa9a9;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 250px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}
.image{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
.line {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  right: -68px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #5dca88;
}
```

Comment: А при решении данной задачи, у вас, где возникли трудности? Опишите что попробовали и почему не получилось.

Comment: Я это к чему. То что вопрос максимально примитивный. Смысла нет задавать такие вопросы. Сообщество максимум может ссылки на хорошие уроки по Web разработке дать.

Comment: Ну вообще там нужно ещё больше сделать, нужно чтобы при нажатии на этот элемент менялся цвет изображения и добавлялся этот элемент, а также менялся контент, который я не вставил

Comment: был бы рад и ссылке на обучение js или фреймворк, который помог бы с этим

Comment: https://codepen.io/Frontend04/pen/rNKryRJ - должно выглядеть так

Comment: Вот [это](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/8.5.php) хороший урок по управлению элементов с помощью обычного JS, [эта глава](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/9.1.php) показывает как создавать события нажатия, перетаскивания и.т.д. [Этот](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/8.7.php) показывает как стили менять. К счастью для вас там и пример есть как цвет менять